# Does a Default Method in java interface is static?

Tags: methods, static, default

Below is the default method in an interface , it is static by default ?
If i am adding static , error is showing as illegal combination of modifiers.

interface Interface{

default void mymethod(){

```
  System.out.println();
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Java 9, methods in interfaces may be only `abstract`, `static`, or `default`. These modifiers are pairwise incompatible. If none modifier is specified, the method is treated as `abstract` (however, you can still specify the modifier `abstract`).

Answer (score 0):

1.`default void mymethod()` it's not static by default.

2.static methods in interface cant only be `public` and `private`.

Reference：

> https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods